# Formatting XElement with tabs

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an existing xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<property_set_list>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet1">
        <property symbol_id="TestName1" id="1" type="8">Test</property>
        <property symbol_id="TestName2" id="2" type="8"></property>
    </property_set>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet2">

    </property_set>
</property_set_list>
```

I load it and update and add some properties. For example:

TestName1 property is updated.
 TestName 2 property stays as it is.

In the TestPropertySet2 I am adding some new properties.

The output of the document after all the manipulation is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<property_set_list>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet1">
        <property symbol_id="TestName1" id="1" type="8">qwerty</property>
        <property symbol_id="TestName2" id="1" type="8">
        </property>
    </property_set>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet2">
        <property symbol_id="localeID" id="1" type="19">1033</property>
        <property symbol_id="localeID" id="2" type="19">1079</property>
    </property_set>
</property_set_list>
```

This is the code I used for loading and manipulating the document:

```
using (var reader = ReaderCreator())
            using (var output = OutputCreator())
            using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(output))
            {
                xmlWriter.Indentation = 1;
                xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlWriter.IndentChar = TAB;

                XDoc = XElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.None);
                Namespace = "some namespace";

               // some code to update properties


                // adds new nodes to TestPropertySet2
                foreach (var localeId in _franchise.LocaleIds)
                {
                    TestPropertySet2.Add(
                        new XElement(
                            Namespace + "property", localeId,
                            new XAttribute("symbol_id", "localeID"),
                            new XAttribute("id", i),
                            new XAttribute("type", "19")
                        )
                    );
                    i++;
                }

                XDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
            }
```

The problem is TestName2 property is on two rows now:

```
<property symbol_id="TestName2" id="1" type="8">
            </property>
```

Comment: Depending on how you want your final XML to look, you can save it using an [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) and setting the `IndentChars` to `\t\t`. This will however indent all the entire document using double tabs. I don't know if you can indent different sections in different ways (without writing your `XmlWriter`). You also need to set `Indent = true` on the `XmlWriterSettings`.

Comment: Following your edit: I don't know why that's happening. I've tested it on my computer and it never splits the `<property>` tags. Perhaps it would help if you could post the (entire) part where you save to file.

Comment: I have updated the whole post. Hope it is more clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your `ReaderCreator()` and `OutputCreator()` methods do. But the following code works by my side as requested.

```
string xml = "<property_set_list><property_set symbol_id=\"TestPropertySet1\"><property symbol_id=\"TestName1\" id=\"1\" type=\"8\">qwerty</property>" +
    "<property symbol_id=\"TestName2\" id=\"1\" type=\"8\"></property></property_set><property_set symbol_id=\"TestPropertySet2\">" +
    "<property symbol_id=\"localeID\" id=\"1\" type=\"19\">1033</property><property symbol_id=\"localeID\" id=\"2\" type=\"19\">1079</property></property_set></property_set_list>";

XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
XElement TestPropertySet2 = xdoc.Elements()
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("symbol_id").Value == "TestPropertySet2")
    .FirstOrDefault();

TestPropertySet2.Add(
    new XElement(
       "property", "locale_id_val",
       new XAttribute("symbol_id", "localeID"),
       new XAttribute("id", "99"),
       new XAttribute("type", "19")
       ));

XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.Indent = true;
xws.IndentChars = "\t\t";

FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create);
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(fs, xws))
{
     xdoc.Save(xw);
}
fs.Close();
```

This produces the following output (indentation maintained):

```
<property_set_list>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet1">
            <property symbol_id="TestName1" id="1" type="8">qwerty</property>
            <property symbol_id="TestName2" id="1" type="8"></property>
    </property_set>
    <property_set symbol_id="TestPropertySet2">
            <property symbol_id="localeID" id="1" type="19">1033</property>
            <property symbol_id="localeID" id="2" type="19">1079</property>
            <property symbol_id="localeID" id="99" type="19">locale_id_val</property>
    </property_set>
```

Please not the use of `XmlWriter` instead of `XmlTextWriter`. I don't know if that's the reason for your problem. This code can be easily adapted to your particular implementation.

Comment: Thank You, Andrei! It worked! The only change I made was replacing XmlTextWriter with Xml Writer. For the record, ReaderCreator() and OutputCreator() are delegates returning TextReader and TextWriter. This helps unit testing the module.